# What is this song playing in episode 5?

Tags: music, parasyte

Does anyone know what song plays at about [5:20 in episode 5](http://www.crunchyroll.com/parasyte-the-maxim-/episode-5-the-stranger-662591)?

Comment: I don't believe this piece is on the first OST. It'll probably show up in the second OST, which I assume will be released within the next few months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sound track is called Migi's Theme. It was kind of difficult to find the name as there don't seem to be too many hits on the Parasyte OSTs, but here is a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nigNVWoqHHU) link to it as well.

Comment: As the YouTube description indicates, this is a re-creation of the piece by some random guy on YouTube. The name "Migi's Theme" is just the name that the guy gave to the song - not the actual name of the piece.

Comment: Yes, however, this is the closest we can get. Even doing a ton of Google searches, there isn't any other hits for this sound track other than Migi's Theme.

Comment: That doesn't make it the answer, though. If I were to post my own recreation of the song to YouTube and title it "Florble Glorble Blorble", that wouldn't make the title of the song "Florble Glorble Blorble" - we simply still wouldn't know what it was callde.

Comment: True, but it's still a fact that the only info that can be found for the theme is "Migi's Theme." The mass amount of results from Google searches supports this.